# Require 8 digits for input field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I've created what I think is a simple validation script that requires

1) The registration field be required and

2) The registration field must be 8 digits in length

However, it's not working. I've excluded the other required fields so they don't get in the way. Can someone tell me if I'm completey out of the ballpark?

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function validateForm(f)
{

// Require Registration
 if (f.registration.value == '' && f.registration.length != 8)
 {
  alert('Please enter your 8-digit registration number.')
  f.registration.focus()
  return false;
 } 

}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="registration" name="registration" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (f.registration.value.length != 8)
 {
  alert('Please enter your 8-digit registration number.')
  f.registration.focus()
  return false;
 }
```

And this function **validateForm**, you need attach on form submit event.

Comment: DOH! Guess that might work. If I require an 8-digit number at the minimum then obviously there has to be a value. That is one big brain fart.

Answer (score 0):

Hows this work

```
if (f.registration.value == '' && f.registration.value.length != 8)
```